# Update dataset in spark-shell by breaking one element into multiple parts and inserting a row for each part

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, apache-spark-dataset

I have a use case where I am storing my data into dataset. I have a column where I can have multiple values in a row separated by pipe(|). So, a typical row looks like this:

```
2016/01/01  1/XYZ   PQR M|N|O
```

I want this row to be converted into 3 rows as follows:

```
2016/01/01  1/XYZ   PQR M
2016/01/01  1/XYZ   PQR N
2016/01/01  1/XYZ   PQR O
```

Also, not all the contents in last column may contain pipe(|).Some rows can be as one of the above. I was trying to split the concerned column with pipe(|), but it is giving error because of rows not containing pipe(|). I couldn’t think any further solution.

What is best way to achieve this using spark-shell in scala.

Comment: what you need is `explode` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case you have to use `split` and `explode`(as mentioned by @Pushkr) both.

```
df.withColumn("new", split($"col4", "[|:]+")).drop("col4").withColumn("col4", explode($"new")).drop("new").show
```

Here `df` is the DataFrame containing **2016/01/01 1/XYZ PQR M|N|O** data. Also, to split by any delimiter you have to build pattern according to your requirements. Like in the code above I am using `[|:]+` pattern to split the string by either `|` or `:`.

For Example:

```
2016/01/01,1/XYZ,PQR,M|N|O
2016/02/02,2/ABC,DEF,P:Q:R
```

Will result in:

```
+-----------+------+----+----+
|       col1|  col2|col3|col4|
+-----------+------+----+----+
|2016/01/01 |1/XYZ |PQR |  M |
|2016/01/01 |1/XYZ |PQR |  N |
|2016/01/01 |1/XYZ |PQR |  O |
|2016/02/02 |2/ABC |DEF |  P |
|2016/02/02 |2/ABC |DEF |  Q |
|2016/02/02 |2/ABC |DEF |  R |
+-----------+------+----+----+
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I have a new problem now. Suppose for the newly created rows, I want to keep one column to have a specific value and others to have some other value. In your result diagram, suppose col3 is integer with value 10. So, in the three rows, in first i want col3 for row1 as 10, and row2 & row3 as 0. How would you go for this.

Comment: @AnantKumar You're welcome!
Ah..for your second scenario could you tell me the condition on the basis of which row gets value 10 and others 0 ?

Comment: Just the first row should have the value 10 and all the others should have value 0.